# ColdFusion cfdump does not show query on Lucee version 5.2.1.9

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

I just updated Lucee to the latest version 5.2.1.9, but I run into a small issue.

When I'm using the `cfdump` tag to debug queries, the dump only shows the rows of the query, but not the SQL query itself.

Can someone help me on this issue?

This issue only started happening when I installed this version and not on the older versions of Lucee.

Answer (score 7):

They have made changes to the `cfdump` tag in version 5.2.

[From the release notes here](https://dev.lucee.org/t/announcing-lucee-5-1-4-and-5-2/2309) (under the Lucee 5.2 Release Notes section)

> **CFDump Tag**
>   The  tag now produces far less output than before. Instead of generating a lot of HTML for all the data in a dump, the tag now outputs the data itself as JSON (string), and generates the output with Javascript. Note: Output type "simple" still generates full HTML, as before.

Try using output type "simple" (and by "output" I think they mean "format").

There are several people commenting on the changes to the `cfdump` tag. You may want to voice your opinion over there.

Comment: Thanks Miguel-f :)
<cfdump var="#query#" format="simple"> - was the right the solutions